# jquery outside $.post function does not work another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here http://jsfiddle.net/r5ktrt51/8/ place something similar, but real code is this

```
var select_id = 0;
get_top_level_categories = true;

if ( get_top_level_categories == true ){

    $.post("___ajax_get_top_level_categories.php", function(top_level_categories) {

    var top_level_categories = $.parseJSON( top_level_categories );

    $('#span_upper_level_name').append( '<select name="upper_level_id' + select_id + '" id="upper_level_id' + select_id + '" class="upper_level_id" width="135" style="width: 136px"></select>' );

    $('<option/>').val('select').html('Select').appendTo('#upper_level_id' + select_id );

    $.map( top_level_categories, function( val ) {
    $('<option/>').val(val.IdRows).html(val.CategoriesName).appendTo('#upper_level_id' + select_id);
    });

    });

}//if ( get_top_level_categories == true ){
```

As result i with firefox addon, with View generated source i see like this

```
 <span id="span_upper_level_name">
 <select name="upper_level_id0" id="upper_level_id0" class="upper_level_id" width="135" style="width: 136px">
 <option value="select">Select</option>
 <option value="2">Transport</option>
 <option value="3">Work and business</option>
 </select>
 </span>
```

Here is `class="upper_level_id"`. So i expect if i change value (option) in drop down box, then would see alert with this code

```
$('.upper_level_id').change(function(){ 
alert('upper_level_id changed');
});
```

But see no alert.

If i place the last code inside `$.post` function, then all works (see alert).

How to get it to work if the last code is outside `$.post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/r5ktrt51/10/

Use

```
$(document).on('change', '.upper_level_id', function(){ 
    alert('upper_level_id changed 2');
});
```

because your elements are dynamically added.

Answer (score 2):

That would be event delegation. When the page loads, the element does not exist; event delegation provides a way of attaching event handlers to present **and future** elements:

```
$(document).on('change', '.upper_level_id', function(){ 
    alert('upper_level_id changed');
});
```

See: [**jQuery.live() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the on change event after the item was added. You can't set it in advance.
You could do something like that in your $.post

```
$('.upper_level_id').change(function(){upperLevelChange();});
```

and outside

```
function upperLevelChange() { alert('upper level id changed'); }
```